# How do I get code::blocks to keep the libraries configured after code::blocks restarts?

Tags: c++, dll, configuration, compiler-errors, codeblocks

When I link the .dll files for the SFML library (as the SFML website says), it works completely normal, but when I restart my IDE (code::blocks), it unlinks all of the libraries. How do I stop this from unlinking?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you link libraries in the *Project->Build options* menu.

If you want to use them for all projects you create or open then use *Settings->Compile*r menu.